# How can I fix a "no instance of function template 'Defer' matches the argument list" error in C++?

Tags: c++, templates

I'm working with a C++ code that I've found online. The creator of this code insists that this code works, but I cant get the code to compile and run no matter what I do. In particular, i'm getting two errors, which are:

> no instance of function template "Defer" matches the argument list

> TDefer<DoPkg::<lambda_cbb42bad95cffc2340696a1e41564dae>> Defer<DoPkg::<lambda_cbb42bad95cffc2340696a1e41564dae>>(T &)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'DoPkg::<lambda_cbb42bad95cffc2340696a1e41564dae>' to 'T&'

The portion of the code where the above two errors are occurring is as follows:

```
bool DoPkg(const wchar_t* pPath, const wchar_t* pOutputPath) {
    std::map<int, FILE*> files;
    int mainPackageIndex = LoadPackages(pPath, files);

    auto defer = Defer([&files]() -> void{
        for (auto it : files){
            fclose(it.second);
        }
    });

    //More Code here...

    return true;
}
```

The function being called in the auto defer part is:

```
template<typename T> TDefer<T> Defer(T & callback){
    return TDefer<T>(callback);
```

I have tried to search for fixes to these issues, but I can't figure out how to fix them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Defer` takes an non-const lvalue reference.  Your lambda expression that you have in the call site creates a temporary object, and temporary objects can't bind to non-const lvalue references.

You either need to change `Defer` to be

```
template<typename T> TDefer<T> Defer(T && callback)
// or
template<typename T> TDefer<T> Defer(T callback)
// or no template and use
TDefer<std::function<void()>> Defer(std::function<void()> callback)
```

So it can accept lvalues and temporaries, or make the lambda an object and then pass it to `Defer` like

```
auto temp = [&files]() -> void{
                for (auto it : files){
                    fclose(it.second);
                }
            };
auto defer = Defer(temp);
```

Comment: @RemyLebeau I've added those alternatives.